# Serve Static HTML files using different route in webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, url-routing, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack to serve my files. I want to get following file.

localhost:5000/callback.html

when I give url. like

localhost:5000/logincallback

How to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In your webpack devServer config, [you can get access to the Express app object](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-setup) and configure a handler for the '/logincallback' route.

Here's a sample devServer section of a larger webpack config object:

```
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    setup(app){
      app.get('/logincallback', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/callback.html'));
      });
    }    
  },
```

Comment: Can I make that folder public? for example I want to get them all with their full path.so that I should also be able to access these files with their path name.

Comment: I was trying to use proxy to do this but that didn't worked. Thank you!